# problems connecting to multifactor connection in share point one drive

Tags: python, sharepoint, onedrive

Hello I have problems with the connection I make from python to share point of one drive and it happens that I want to access an excel file but I have this error.
There was an error retrieving the XML response token: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you have moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import io
import pandas as pd

# File URL in SharePoint and credentials
url = 'https://companymy.sharepoint.com/personal/yo_compnay/Documents/prueba/document.xlsx'
username = 'yo@mycompany.com'
password = 'xxxx'

# Create authentication context
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)

# Attempt to acquire token with user authentication (username and password)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    # If authentication succeeds, create client context.
    ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth).

    # Get the binary file
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

    # Store data in a BytesIO stream object
    bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
    bytes_file_obj.seek(0) # Set file object at startup

    # Read the Excel file and each sheet in a pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name=None).
else:
    print("Error: failed multifactor authentication.")
```